# How to batch generate bpy.props?

Tags: python

How can we batch generate properties, let say i would like to have

```
my_pattern_slot1 : bpy.props.PointerProperty(..ect.)
my_pattern_slot2 : bpy.props.PointerProperty(..ect.)
my_pattern_slot3 : bpy.props.PointerProperty(..ect.)
my_pattern_slot4 : bpy.props.PointerProperty(..ect.)
my_pattern_slot5 : bpy.props.PointerProperty(..ect.)
..ect..
```

in my plugin property structure, w/o repeating my code ?

Note that i am aware of `bpy.props.CollectionProperty` and it's usage,
however here in my context, I do not care to have an undefined amount of properties. Having the index baked in the property name is what I'm looking for

Comment: May be write a code to generate the string as code?

Comment: i believe that running exec() or eval() didn't worked here, because properties are being declared, not evaluated

Comment: I will copy the code in console to the .py file. It works but not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of registering a property in typical a `PropertyGroup` structure, we need to register them in the `__annotation__` python object. Blender is a bit special in this case, i believe annotations, and type declaration are only meant as an informal goal in python, but here it plays a key role on registering the property itself.

Here is how we can batch generate properties with the help of a function.

```py
def batch_declare_properties( name="my_prop_XX", property_type=None, nbr=20, items={},):
    """this fct goal is to generate redundant the properies declaration, use XX or X as idx placeholder in your property name or label"""

    declarations = {}

    for i in (n+1 for n in range(nbr)):

        #adjust propname depending on index
        if ("XX" in name):
            prop_name = name.replace("XX",f"{i:02}")
        elif ("X" in name):
            prop_name = name.replace("X",f"{i}")
        else: 
            raise Exception("batch_declare_properties->forgot to use the XX or X kewords")

        kwargs = items.copy()

        #adjust label depending on index?
        if ("name" in kwargs.keys()):
            to_replace = "XX" if ("XX" in kwargs["name"]) else "X" if ("X" in kwargs["name"]) else ""
            if to_replace:        
                kwargs["name"] = kwargs["name"].replace(to_replace, f" {i}")

        #add property to dict
        declarations[prop_name] = property_type(**kwargs)
        
        continue

    return declarations
```

And in the PropertyGroup it looks like this
please pay attention to `__annotations__.update(declarations)`

```
class SCATTER5_PROP_particle_systems(bpy.types.PropertyGroup): 

    __annotations__.update( codegen_properties_by_idx(
        name="my_patternX_allow", property_type=bpy.props.BoolProperty, nbr=3, items={
        "description":translate("Influence your instances scale and density with a texture-pattern"),
        "default":False,
        },),)
    __annotations__.update( codegen_properties_by_idx(
        name="my_patternX_texture_ptr", property_type=bpy.props.StringProperty, nbr=3, items={
        "description":"Internal property that will update a TEXTURE_NODE node tree from given nodetree name, used for presets and most importantly copy/paste or synchronization",
        },),)
    __annotations__.update( codegen_properties_by_idx(
        name="my_patternX_id_color_ptr", property_type=bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty, nbr=3, items={
        "name":translate("ID Value"),
        "subtype":"COLOR",
        "min":0,
        "max":1,
        "default":(1,0,0),
        },),)
```

This code generation technique is also very handy if you have a lot of properties dedicated for the UI, for example in my project i have a lot of properties for opening/closing GUI, with by changing a little this function you can search in your whole plugin text for specific keywords and generate the properties accordingly

```
def generate_all_my_ui_properties():
    """codegen for registering all ui open/close properties for toggles
    usage: leave commented keywords such as CODEGEN_REGTIME:UI_PSYBOOL_KEY:"my_prop";UI_PSYBOOL_VAL:"0" and the function will generate the properties automatically"""

    d,keywords,defaults = {},[],[]

    for py in get_my_plugin_modules():
        with open(py,'r') as f:
            txt = f.read()
            keywords += re.findall(r'CODEGEN_REGTIME:UI_PSYBOOL_KEY:"(.*?)"', txt,)
            defaults += re.findall(r'UI_PSYBOOL_VAL:"(.*?)"', txt,)
         continue

    for (prop_name,default) in zip(keywords,defaults):
        if prop_name not in d.keys():
            d[prop_name] = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=int(default),)
        continue

    return d
```

I do believe it might be a good idea to create your own subclass of a bpy.props, but i did not mess with such class structure yet